# Convert full name input to last name + initials

Tags: python

Write a program in python whose input is:

firstName middleName lastName

and whose output is:

lastName, firstInitial.middleInitial.

Ex: If the input is:

```
Pat Silly Doe
```

the output is:

```
Doe, P.S.
```

If the input has the form:

```
firstName lastName
```

the output is:

```
lastName, firstInitial.
```

Ex: If the input is:

```
Julia Clark
```

the output is:

```
Clark, J.
```

all without using if then statements.

this is what I have so far which works for three names but not two names.

```py
user_name = input(' ').split()

print('{}, {}.{}.'.format(user_name[2], user_name[0][0], user_name[1][0]))
```

Comment: hint: consider combining `join` and slicing (eg `'.'.join(["Pat", "Silly"])`

Comment: You cannot use that format string as it contains the two periods and if your input has not middle name you only need one.  You also cannot use join, at least as is, because it separator but you need end of word period.

Comment: I need both the periods though if it has three names

Comment: Also title doesn't seem to have anything to do with the problem. You don't get a dictionary input, you get a string, so you need to convert that to a dict?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you do not use a dictionary in your code, I just provide a solution without dict.

```
name = input("Name: ").split()
print(f"{name.pop()}, {''.join(n[0] + '.' for n in name)}")
```

`name.pop()` gets the last name in list, `n[0] + '.'` gets the initials for the remaining names and adds a dot after them, then we use `join()` to combine these initials.

Test run:

```
Name: Pat Silly Doe
Doe, P.S.
Name: Julia Clark
Clark, J.
```

Comment: this is great could I bother you to explain the f in the print statement for me and why {these brackets}? this answered my question I just want to know how it all works so I don't get stuck again. thank you.

Comment: @DerekPruitt format string or f-string is something new starts from python 3.6. It works similar to `"{}".format()` you are using, but you can put the variables, expressions or values you want directly into those `{}`, you just need to inform python to format it by adding an `f` before the string. More info on [Formatted string literals](https://docs.python.org/3/reference/lexical_analysis.html#f-strings) and [Format String Syntax](https://docs.python.org/3/library/string.html#formatstrings).

Comment: The answer doesn't use a dictionary, and result is in a different forma than requestedt.  If this is the accepted answer please change question to match so others don't get confused.

Comment: how do I edit my question and I do appreciate everyone's help

Answer (score 1):

I would skip the dictionary (d) but it seems to be a requirement for you:

```
def initials(a):
    return ''.join(map(lambda s: s[0] + '.', a))


def abbreviate(s):
    l = s.split()
    d = {'lastName': l[-1], 'initials': initials(l[0:-1])}
    return '{}, {}'.format(d['lastName'], d['initials'])


for n in ('Pat Silly Doe', 'Julia Clark'):
    print(abbreviate(n))
```

and this will give you the output:

```
Doe, P.S
Clark, J.
```

Here is a fancier version using `zip()` to combine the keys and values and converted into a dictionary with `dict()`:

```
def abbreviate(s):
    l = s.rsplit(maxsplit=1)
    d = dict(
        zip(
            ('lastName', 'initials'),
            (
                l[1],
                ''.join(map(lambda s2: s2[0] + '.', l[0].split()))
            )
        )
    )
    return f"{d['lastName']}, {d['initials']}"
```

Comment: this is great, I just cant use this. I should have put in there that I can use dictionary's and string methods and list, because that is what the chapter is on. what is map and lambda?

Comment: d is your dictionary.  `join()` is a string method.   map is documented here https://docs.python.org/3.9/library/functions.html#map, and lambda here https://docs.python.org/3/reference/expressions.html#lambda

Answer (score 0):

```
input_name = "First Second Third"
split_names = input_name.split(" ")
print(split_names[-1] + ", " + "".join([s[0].upper() +"." for s in split_names[:-1] ]))
```

Comment: According to the question, the last name should come first, so your code does not provide the expected result. Also, better not to use `input` as variable name as it will override the built-in `input()` function.

Answer (score 0):

If you just need a one-liner

```
f'{user_name.split()[-1]}, {".".join(word[0] for word in user_name.split()[:-1])}.'
```